# JQuery mobile enable/disable different from JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a desktop website that has been around for years and I'm now building a mobile version with JQM. One problem I came across was to enable a form element, specifically a dropdown like so:

```
$('#dropdown').removeAttr('disabled');
```

This works for the desktop version but not for JQM. I have to do:

```
$('#dropdown').selectmenu('enable');
```

Isn't JQM based on JQuery? Why do I need something different and now need to keep separate javascript files depending on the platform?

Comment: You tried `$("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true)`?

Comment: because jQM UI is different than _native_ `select`. It wraps it in a div to give it a different look. and btw, its `.selectmenu()`, a widget of jQM. If you don't want jQM UI simply add `data-role="none"` to `select`.

Comment: Yes prop is not affective either.

Comment: Typo sorry I meant selectmenu. So if I expect the original JS code to work, I can only revert to native select?

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: Yes, if you use native selectmenu, native jQuery code will work.